# Unsigned field updated to max value

Tags: mysql, sql, unsigned

I'm having problems to make this simple query work:

```
INSERT INTO stock
( articles_id, date, in, out ) 
VALUES 
( 106,  '2017-08-24', 0, 4 ) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE out = IF( out - 4 >= 0, out - 4, 0 )
```

This is the structure of the stock table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock` (
  `articles_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `in` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'new units in date',
  `out` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'no. of units sold in date'
  PRIMARY KEY  (`articles_id`,`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The queried record already exists, and has these values:

1. articles_id: 106
2. date: 2017-08-24
3. in: 0
4. **out: 2**

After the query is run, *out* has a value of **16777215**, which I guess is since this field is *unsigned* (I want it that way), if I substract a bigger value than the original, it begins counting down from its max value.

However, shouldn't my *IF* statement prevent that behavior??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the *incoming* values, so use `values()`:

```
INSERT INTO stock( articles_id, date, in, out ) 
    VALUES ( 106,  '2017-08-24', 0, 4 ) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE out = (CASE WHEN VALUES(out) - 4 >= 0
                                        THEN VALUES(out) - 4
                                        ELSE 0
                                   END);
```

Comment: So I guess (out - 4) is not taking its value, but it's operating on the field itself, thus getting this value: 16777215 which since it's bigger than 0, it enters the first condition and eventually does the substraction.